# Removing specks from shape in R

Tags: shapefile, r, sf

After dissolving inner boundaries, [this sf shape [Pastebin]](https://pastebin.com/cGyEm9sq) retains residual specks or crumbs:

```
library(sf)

#download file "shp.txt" from Pastebin
shp <- dget("shp.txt")

class(shp)
[1] "sfc_MULTIPOLYGON" "sfc"

plot(shp)
```

[image: shape before]

I have tried 2 different methods of removing them but both fall short:

```
#CRS is in meters so that threshold parameters are expressed in square meters in both methods
st_crs(shp)$units 
[1] "m"

#Method #1
library(rmapshaper)
shp <- ms_filter_islands(shp, min_area=1000000)
plot(shp)
```

Method #1 fails to remove at least one tiny speck in the centre of the shape:

[image: shape after]

```
#Method #2
library(smoothr)
shp <- drop_crumbs(shp, threshold=1000000)
plot(shp)
```

Method #2 doesn't do anything, apparently.

What are substitute or complementary ways of accomplishing the task?

Comment: What type of spatial object is your data on pastebin? Also, take a look at this QA: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264562/eliminating-small-polygons-from-shapefile-after-polygonize-in-r

Comment: It's an `sf` object.

Comment: @Aaron The linked answer is for polygons but some specks might be lines or points, for all I know. The answer seems to apply to a different object type. The answer also refers to `rmapshaper`, which my question includes.

Comment: One hack is to use a buffer/negative-buffer to clean up small polygons and holes. Keep in mind though that this approach can smooth polygons, especially if you use too big of a buffer size.

Comment: I flagged my question to be transferred to StackOverflow, considering the relatively low attention it is getting here (GIS-SE) and my experience of getting fast answers to computational geospatial questions on SO. My flag was declined with the argument that the question is on topic for GIS-SE. However, I am still waiting as a result. Should I consequently cross-post in SO, in accordance with [this answer on Meta-SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234946/767058)? I submit that this moderation policy discourages from posting this type of question here instead of on SO in the first place.

Comment: Regarding cross-posting, I would encourage you to follow these guidelines: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/641151. Regarding your question, I'm not entirely sure why it has not received more attention. There may be an issue with the pastebin data you provided as I was unable to generate the sf object.

Comment: @Aaron The Pastebin file may be too large to copy-paste so I've amended the OP with code to upload it, which works fine on my side.